# Java - HTTP Status 404 – Not Found

Tags: java, spring-mvc, web-applications, http-status-code-404

I'm studying spring mvc and want to test some very simple annotation-based controllers,It works fine on home page but when I enter */home/user* it gives me **HTTP Status 404 – Not Found** error and I haven't found anything to fix it.

web.xml

```
<web-app version="3.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd">
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <!--####################################-->


    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>2</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>dispatcher</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>redirect.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

dispatcher-servlet.xml

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
       xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.support.ControllerClassNameHandlerMapping"/>

    <context:component-scan base-package="spring" />

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping"/>

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter"/>

    <bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/jsp/"/>
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp"/>
    </bean>

    <!--<bean id="viewResolver"

</beans>
```

HomeController.java

```
package spring.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

@Controller
//@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/home", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomeMessage() {
        return "home";
    }
}
```

UserController.java

```
package spring.controllers;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeMessage(){
        return "user";
    }
}
```

**redirect.jsp** just uses `sendRedirect()` method and redirects to **home.jsp**.

**home.jsp** and **user.jsp** just prints a simple *hello* message

Where I'm doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: Have you tried changing the request mapping of user to `/user` for your `UserController` rather than leveraging the request mapping of `/home` that you have defined for a method in your `HomeController`? I suspect that is where your issue is occurring.

Comment: @JacobBlanton yes, same error. I really can't understand what's wrong with this simple code

Comment: You commented out `@RequestMapping(value = "/home")` in `HomeController` and mapped it to the method. Have you tried moving `@RequestMapping("/home/user")` down to the method? In effect, `UserController` is patterned from `HomeController`.

Comment: @jpllosa yes, I tried it too. Same error.

Comment: Have you tried nesting the `RequestMapping`?

Comment: @jpllosa what do u mean by "Nesting the `RequestMapping` " ?

Comment: See nested `RequestMapping` example below.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried nesting the `RequestMapping`? Something like this...

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value = "/home")
public class HomeController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String showHomeMessage() {
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/user", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeMessage(){
        return "user";
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if you need to put a value on `showHomeMessage` (i.e. `value="/"`).

Comment: It worked!!!! BUT HOW?? why my code doesn't work?! i Can't do all the processing in one controller.

Answer (score 0):

After looking through [this](https://dzone.com/articles/spring-framework-restcontroller-vs-controller) little example, I think your issue is tied to the fact that you are not specifying the `@ResponseBody` using the `@Controller` annotation. Whereas, if you use the `@RequestController` annotation simply implying a String type would be sufficient because it combines the use of `@Controller` and `@ResponseBody`

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/home/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public @ResponseBody String welcomeMessage(){
        return "user";
    }
}
```

The alternative to the same block would be...

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/home/user")
public class UserController {

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String welcomeMessage(){
        return "user";
    }
}
```

Of course this little example doesnt demonstrate `MediaType` and so forth, but hopefully you get the idea.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have read 5-6 tutorials and examples and almost none of them! uses `@ResponseBody`. So I even don't know what is it and why should i use it